# How can I add <!DOCTYPE html> inside an iframe in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I've created an IFrame with no src in my GWT project but as I don't have `<!DOCTYPE html>` inside it some css properties are being overriden by the user agent stylesheet. Is there any way I can add `<!DOCTYPE html>` inside the IFrame element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you want to have an empty `iframe` to manipulate programmatically.

The easiest way is to create minimal html file with `<!DOCTYPE html>` and set `src` attribute to that file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Save this file is the `war` folder as `empty.html` for example. Then use:

```java
IFrameElement iframe = Document.get().createIFrameElement();
iframe.setSrc("empty.html");
```

to get `Element`. If you want to have a `Widget` add:

```java
new HTML(iframe.toString());
```

Comment: I am creating the Iframe with `IFrameElement` class in GWT so is there anyway I can do that?